# JS vanilla set variable with await an async function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have an asynchronous function that waits for a call to an API, once it receives the requested data it enters in a for loop passing the single values ​​to a second API, waiting for every single call, everything works correctly, now I need to pass an additional parameter in the call inside the for loop, obtained by calling a second function.

I instantiated the "transactionID" variable as empty outside the loop, now before entering the for loop I have to retrieve its value by calling the getSessionId () function, unfortunately something is wrong and the variable is always undefined.

I need the value once and out of the loop, because it will always be the same in the for loop.

I have tried different ways and calling the function in different places, but the variable continues to be undefined, what am I wrong?

```
const carAndiuv = async ArrayCarrelliPagamento => {
  let qtIuv = 0,
    totIuv = 0,
    percBar = $("prog-bar"),
    percentuale = 0,
    uniqueCodeOfCart = "",
    transactionID = "";

    // Get all the cart
    await ajaxPost("/utility/API/recuperIuvCarrelli", {
      token: CEDtoken.token_type + " " + CEDtoken.id_token,
      id_carrelli: JSON.stringify({ ...ArrayCarrelliPagamento }),
    }).then(async data => {
      if (data.errCon == null) {
        qtIuv = Object.keys(data).length;

        transactionID = await getSessionId();
        console.log("TID est: " + transactionID); // returns undefined

        // Loop the elements
        for (let sel in data) {
          console.log("TID int: " + transactionID); // returns undefined
          await ajaxPost("/utility/API/inviaPagamentiPagopa", {
            token: API.token_type + " " + API.access_token,
            codIuv: data[sel],
            UniqueCodeOfCart: uniqueCodeOfCart,
            TransactionID: transactionID, // TransactionID is undefined
          }).then(async iuv => {
            uniqueCodeOfCart = iuv.UniqueCodeOfCart;
            totIuv++;
            percentuale = (((100 * totIuv) / qtIuv) | 0) + "%";
            // Percentage bar animation
            percBar.style.width = percBar.textContent = percentuale;
            percBar.setAttribute("aria-valuenow", percentuale);

          });
        }

      } else {
        console.log("Connection error");
        changeStatusOnline();
        tryReconnect();
      }
    });
};

const getSessionId = async () => {
  ajaxPost("/utility/API/getSessionId", {
    token: API + " " + API.access_token,
  }).then(data => data.SessionID);
};
```

Comment: `getSessionId` doesn't return anything

Comment: `.then(data => data.SessionID);` It's equal to `.then(data => {return data.SessionID});` or I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: Ok, I get it, I'm an idiot, I return but not in the main function, thanks @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `await` and `.then` callbacks at the same time, which is not exactly correct way to return values from the `async` function. When you're using `await` keyword, asynchronous function will be called and the result of this function will return as soon, as `Promise` resolves.

As seen in your example, `getSessionId` does not wait `ajaxPost` to be completed and not returning anything. If you need to return data from the request and return it back, you should use `await` keyword when calling `ajaxPost` and then return needed data:

```js
const getSessionId = async () => {
    // First, you call `ajaxPost` and wait. Result of the execution will
    // return to `result`
    const data = await ajaxPost("/utility/API/getSessionId", {
        token: API + " " + API.access_token,
    });
    
    return data.SessionID;
};
```

Same goes for the `ajaxPost` call in your `ArrayCarrelliPagamento` function, but there might be problems with logic, if you simply convert it.

You might need to read more about [`await` keyword and its usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).